# When is deleting a template instantiation preferable to deleting a non-template overload?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

Suppose I have a template that works with raw pointers:

```
template<typename T>
void processPointer(T* ptr);
```

I don't want this to be called with `void*` pointers. It seems I have two choices. I can delete a non-template overload:

```
void processPointer(void*) = delete;
```

Or I can delete a template instantiation:

```
template<>
void processPointer<void>(void*) = delete;
```

Declaring the non-template overload is easier (no futzing with angle brackets). Are there reasons why I'd prefer to delete the template instantiation instead?

Comment: +1, because I don't know the answer myself. I'd delete the template instantiation because I tend to think of the whole set of overloads as templates. I think it would be easier to understand what's going on later, when reading the code (i.e. follow the principle of least surprise). I don't know if there are technical reasons to choose one way or another.

Answer (score 25):

[Here's one reason](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdd716badcd72bf1) to favor the template version: `processPointer<void>(void*)` can still be invoked directly, avoiding the other overload.

Comment: +1 as specifying the template argument explicitly is quite common in generic code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason to go templating here

In fact, by deleting the non-template overload you may wiggle your way out of some edge-case ambiguous calls that I can't think of right now, since non-templates take precedence over template instantiations. And thus make this work as desired in a majority of cases.

Answer (score 4):

This might give insight:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    template<typename T>
    void processPointer(T* ptr) {
        std::cout << "Template\n";
    }

    // error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct X’
    // template<>
    // void processPointer(void*) = delete;

    // Overload but no specialization
    // This will prevent lookup the specialization outside the class, when no
    // template argument is explicitly given.  However, with an explicit 
    // template argument the specialization is called.
    void processPointer(void*) = delete;
};

// Specialization outside the class body
template<>
void X::processPointer(void* ptr) {
    std::cout << "Specialization\n";
}

int main ()
{
    X x;
    //error: use of deleted function ‘void X::processPointer(void*)’
    //x.processPointer((void*)0);

    // Explicit template argument:
    x.processPointer<void>((void*)0);
}
```

Conclusion: The answer of @Casey holds.

Comment: What insight do you think that might give? (I *think* I know, but since you didn't actually say, I'm not sure. Please write a sentence or two to reiterate what the code is supposed to illustrate.)

Comment: `template<> void X::processPointer<void>(void*) = delete;` or without the parameter deduced `template<>
void X::processPointer(void*) = delete;` [can be specialized outside the class scope](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5e781c971aa54b0 "Demo code at Coliru").

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to pass the argument `pointer` of type `void*` (or simply `nullptr`) to your `processPointer` function and you also want to call its specialization for type `Type`. Then you should write

```
processPointer(static_cast<Type>(pointer));
```

for

```
void processPointer(void*) = delete;
```

But for

```
template<>
void processPointer<void>(void*) = delete;
```

you could write the code which is much shorter:

```
processPointer<Type>(pointer);
```

So both variants can be used in the different cases.

However the analogue of the variant with non-template overload can be the only way in some cases.
Suppose there is a function template with two parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void processPointer(T* ptr1, U* ptr2);
```

You don't want it to be called with `void*` pointers as the first argument. The partial specialization of function templates is not allowed in C++ so this code is incorrect:

```
template<typename U>
void processPointer<void, U>(void*, U*) = delete;
```

And you must use another one:

```
template<typename U>
void processPointer(void*, U*) = delete;
```